# Kotlin: Use a lambda in place of a functional interface?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, kotlin

In Java we can do this
`Events.handler(Handshake.class, hs -> out.println(hs));`

In Kotlin however I am trying to replicate the behavior to replace this:

```
Events.handler(Handshake::class, object : EventHandler<Handshake> {
    override fun handle(event: Handshake) {
        println(event.sent)
    }
})
```

With a more convenient:

`Events.handler(Handshake::class, EventHandler<Handshake> { println(it.sent) })`

For some reason in reference to `EventHandler`:

[image]

More preferably however I'd like to use something even shorter like this:
`Events.handler(Handshake::class, { println(it.sent) })`

Or use the advertised feature to use the method like this:
`Events.handler(Handshake::class) { println(it.sent) }`

This is my `Events` object:

```
import java.util.*
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

object Events {

    private val map = HashMap<Class<*>, Set<EventHandler<*>>>()

    fun <T : Any> handler(eventType: KClass<T>, handler: EventHandler<T>) {
        handler(eventType.java, handler)
    }

    fun <T> handler(eventType: Class<T>, handler: EventHandler<T>) = handlers(eventType).add(handler)

    fun post(event: Any) = handlers(event.javaClass).forEach { it.handle(event) }

    operator fun plus(event: Any) = post(event)

    private fun <T> handlers(eventType: Class<T>): HashSet<EventHandler<T>> {
        var set = map[eventType]
        if (set == null) {
            set = HashSet<EventHandler<*>>()
            map.put(eventType, set)
        }
        return set as HashSet<EventHandler<T>>
    }

}
```

And my `EventHandler` interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface EventHandler<T> {

    fun handle(event: T)

}
```

Comment: Did you try `Handshake::class.java` for the first argument? In any case, try Ctrl + P to view the possible parameters of the function.

Comment: `Events.handler(Handshake::class) { println(it.sent) }` — this syntax has nothing to do with inline functions

Comment: OP doesn't understand the meaning of inline functions.

Comment: @cypressious Yes I did try that. I updated the question with the method signatures for `handler`.
@AndreyBreslav @Jonathan-Beaudoin Adjusted the initial question.

Comment: @AndreyBreslav I noticed you answered a similar question here https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/461516 Are SAM conversion to Kotlin lambdas a project in consideration? Is there anything I can do in my current situation besides use Kotlin lambdas?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A lot of nice things has happened to Kotlin since @andrey-breslav posted the answer. He mentions:

> It is that Kotlin **only does SAM-conversion for functions defined in
>   Java**. Since Events.handler is defined in Kotlin, SAM-conversions do
>   not apply to it.

Well, that's no longer the case for [Kotlin 1.4+](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-4-m1-released/). It can use SAM-conversion for Kotlin functions if you mark an interface as a "functional" interface:

```kotlin
// notice the "fun" keyword
fun interface EventHandler<T> {
    fun handle(event: T)
}
```

You can read the YouTrack ticket here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770. There's also an explanation why Kotlin needs a marker for such interfaces unlike Java (`@FunctionalInterface` is only informational and [has no effect on the compiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)).

Comment: This should be now the accepted answer for kotlin 1.4+

Answer (score 86):

Assuming below that you really need `EventHandler` as a separate interface (e.g. for Java interop). If you don't, you can simply use a type alias (since Kotlin 1.1):

```
typealias EventHandler<T> = (T) -> Unit
```

In this case a simple lambda will work right away.

But if you don't want to use a type alias, the issue still stands. It is that Kotlin only does SAM-conversion for functions defined in Java. Since `Events.handler` is defined in Kotlin, SAM-conversions do not apply to it.

To support this syntax:

```
Events.handler(Handshake::class, EventHandler<Handshake> { println(it.sent) })
```

You can define a function named `EventHandler`:

```
fun <T> EventHandler(handler: (T) -> Unit): EventHandler<T> 
    = object : EventHandler<T> { 
        override fun handle(event: T) = handler(event) 
    }
```

To support this syntax:

```
Events.handler(Handshake::class, { println(it.sent) })
```

or this:

```
Events.handler(Handshake::class) { println(it.sent) }
```

You need to overload the `handler` function to take a function instead of `EventHandler`:

```
fun <T> Events.handler(eventType: Class<T>, handler: (T) -> Unit) = EventHandler(handler)
```

Comment: With a little modification I got this to work for my case. Resulting code: http://pastebin.com/tsLfFxnq thanks!

Comment: Also I was able to get it to work with just `KClass` which can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/mEWhA5yc

Comment: @andrey, Do we have above feature (using function where ever SAM  is required) in Kotlin now?

Comment: @mhshams nothing has changed since a month ago

Comment: @AndreyBreslav Nice to hear that type aliases are going to be supported. Is there a publicly available early design document for them? Couldn't find anything like that at https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-spec/

Comment: @Suseika no, there's not enough design work done to publish anything

Comment: @AndreyBreslav now that type aliases are out could you update your answer please?

Comment: That's a pity... Seems it is much easier to write a functional interface in Java. Writing an extra extension function for every interface is not what we expect from Kotlin, @AndreyBreslav