# How to create an Object in Kotlin using a constructor which takes a generic interface and other parameters

Tags: kotlin, assertj

I'm using AssertJ in Kotlin and tried to use an AssertJ-Condition.

The constructor is defined like this:

```
Condition(Predicate<T> predicate, String description, Object... args)
```

See http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/Condition.html

But I can't get the creation right. I tried the following (and some more, which I omitted for brevity):

```
Condition<File>({ it.name.startsWith("functional_questions") }, "Description")
```

with this error: [image]

```
Condition<File>({ file -> file.name.startsWith("functional_questions") }, "Description")
```

with this error:
[image]

How can i succeed?

Comment: whats happen if you use `{ file: File -> ... }` ?

Comment: Same as it is still a `(File) -> Boolean`, not a `Predicate<File>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can come up with is:

```
Condition<File>(Predicate<File> { file -> file.name.startsWith("functional_questions") }, "description")
```

Edit: Your code does not work because Kotlin lambda by default does not implement the required interface. If you run the following code:

```
val predicate1 = { file: File -> file.name.startsWith("functional_questions") }
val predicate2 = Predicate<File> { file -> file.name.startsWith("functional_questions") }

predicate1::class.java.interfaces.forEach { println(it) }
println() //new line to separate outputs
predicate2::class.java.interfaces.forEach { println(it) }
```

you get the following output:

```
interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1

interface java.util.function.Predicate
```

The difference is obvious.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I really don't understand, why the above code does not.

Comment: As code-improvement, I would recommend using `it` or a speaking descriptor like `file`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, see my edit for more information.

Answer (score 1):

AssertJ has no special support for Kotlin as far as I can see, therefore only the Java Predicate is supported.

See more here regarding why we cannot pass kotlin lambdas as functional interfaces: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33610615/5335131

Here are two ways to make it work:

```
@Test fun assertj() {
    Condition<File>(Predicate { it.name.startsWith("functional_questions") }, "Description")
    condition<File>("Description") { it.name.startsWith("functional_questions") }
}

fun <T> condition(description: String, predicate: (T) -> Boolean) =
    Condition<T>(Predicate<T> { predicate(it) }, description)
```

First with a explicit Predicate and second with a helper.