# Kotlin type-safe builders

Tags: kotlin

I use the Kotlin "type-safe builder" pattern in my code:

```
insteadOf("search", "forest|ground") {
    println("Do something.");
}
```

However, I am also using Kryo to serialize data (save a game), and Kryo doesn't like the anonymous type:

```
call: () -> Unit
```

So I had to introduce a "Do"-interface instead of the above type. But now my code looks a lot uglier:

```
insteadOf("search", "forest|ground", object : World.InsteadOf.Do {
     override fun invoke() {
          println("Do something")
     }
})
```

How can I use the simple { } - syntax with the Do-interface?

### **EDIT:**

Here's some clarification.

I'm kind of confused (not news).

The actual Kryo error message seems to be about no-args constructor, however instantly after that it says: "This is an anonymous class, which is not serializable by default in Kryo.".

Here is the full error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): fi.starstuff.rogue.World$insteadOf$1
    This is an anonymous class, which is not serializable by default in Kryo. Possible solutions: 1. Remove uses of anonymous classes, including double brace initialization, from the containing class. This is the safest solution, as anonymous classes don't have predictable names for serialization.
    2. Register a FieldSerializer for the containing class and call FieldSerializer#setIgnoreSyntheticFields(false) on it. This is not safe but may be sufficient temporarily. Use at your own risk.
Serialization trace:
call (com.mygame.World$InsteadOf)
insteadOfs (com.mygame.World)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo$DefaultInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(Kryo.java:1319)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstantiator(Kryo.java:1127)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstance(Kryo.java:1136)
```

Here's the InsteadOf-class:

```
class InsteadOf {
        var verbs: Array<String> = arrayOf()
        var nouns: Array<String> = arrayOf()
        var where: String = ""
        var call: (() -> Unit)? = null
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't like the anonymous type"?

Answer (score 1):

You can basically accept a `() -> Unit` function in `insteadOf` and wrap it into a `Do` instance in the body:

```
fun insteadOf(foo: String, bar: String, call: () -> Unit) { 
    val doInstance = World.InsteadOf.Do(call)
    /* use doInstance */
}
```

The usages will stay the same as in your first example.

Alternatively, provide the `Do` interface with a factory function that accepts `() -> Unit` and returns a `Do` instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what's wrong with your code.
But if you are missing a no-args constructor there are two ways:

1. Obviously add it
2. use `no-arg` [compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin) to specify class that need extra constructor
   `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg`

A lot of serialisation-related libs force user to have no-arg constructor.'
There is a related [issue](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/issues/5) in kryo github.

In case your problem is not related to `no-arg` - your question will be a duplicate for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590646/kotlin-use-a-lambda-in-place-of-a-functional-interface)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I simply ended up switching to core Java serialization and the problem went away.